# How to install .bat or .exe file as a windows service?

Tags: windows, windows-services

How to using bat file or cmd command to install .bat or .exe file as a windows service?

Answer (score -1):

You could run this in your cmd to install or uninstall:

### Install

```
sc create send_service binPath= "E:\Release\abcd.exe" DisplayName= "ABCD windows Serivce" start= auto
```

### Uninstall

```
sc delete send_service
```

Comment: Does this actually work with arbitrary binaries? I'm pretty sure that [service programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-programs) have interface requirements to interact with the service control manager.

Comment: Yes, you are right. EXE file must be build by the Windows Service component.